# Google Charts: how to retrive 3 columns from database and display them as 3 bar in column chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-visualization

How to build google chart (column) if I want to retrive data from  3 columns of database and display them as a row in column chart (`hAxis`) , that means:-

1. there will be a three bar ( called from 3 columns of database)
2. i want to label each of bar with (criteria1, criteria 2, criteria3..)
3. clear example like table below..i just want to retrieve the percentage from database that are stored in 3 columns..  the criteria will be labeled manually..

   ```
    ________________________
   |CRITERIA   |PERCENTAGE |
   |-----------------------|
   |CRITERIA 1 | 64.1      |
   |-----------------------|
   |CRITERIA 2 | 11.1      |
   |-----------------------|
   |CRITERIA 3 | 21.1      |
   |-----------------------|
   ```

   thank u very much..

Edited : getdata.php

```
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array
   (
    array('label' => 'Criteria', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Criteria 1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Criteria 2', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Criteria 3', 'type' => 'number')
    );

   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) 
   {
          $temp = array();
          $temp[] = array('v' =>"");
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float)$r['resultsd']);
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float)$r['resultwe']); 
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float)$r['resulttre']); 

          $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

   }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
```

Comment: Post code and tell what you have tried.

Comment: @vorrtex..see my code..i wrote it via json table and call it in visualization script as url: getdata.php this code can display 3 bar for  column chart but i can't write each bar as criteria 1, criteria 2, criteria 3..

Comment: anybody please help me..

Comment: I don't know php, and Google Charts is a javascript framework, so you should write some javascript code. I can give you a link to the charts documentation where you can find a simple example and adapt it to your data: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

Comment: please....anyone who know please look at my code...

Comment: Ok, at least post what response is returned if you request the `getdata.php` page.

Comment: with above code..my column chart displayed 3 bar..just like i need..but doesnt have any label in each bar..

Comment: Do you want labels on the bars (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/xkf39/1/)) or labels on the axis (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/xkf39/2/))?

Comment: no..label on the axis...label on the bars i know to do it..(annotation) but i want label on the axis which is not called from the database..